# How to overlay two images with position and scale in imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick

Given these two images of size 512x512 with transparent background:

`circle.png`

[image]

`inner.png`

[image]

I'd like to overlay these two images, so that they appear centered and shrink the image size down to say 64x64. My initial attempt looks like:

```
convert -background none inner.png circle.png -layers flatten -resize 64x64 output.png
```

This produces:

[image]

From a design perspective, the inner image looks a bit too large relatively, so I'd like to scale it down a little bit. And despite being technically centered, I'd prefer to move it a little bit to the right, but without increasing the total width of the image. I think this requires to use `-geometry`. I have tried many combinations, but I never get the desired effect. For instance

```
convert -background none inner.png -geometry 256x256 circle.png -layers flatten -resize 64x64 output.png
```

produces

[image]

In a sense the inner image has become smaller relatively, but not in the way I expected.

Any ideas how this can be accomplished with imagemagick?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you wouldn't composite these in Pshop/Gimp first, then export at the required size as a single image?

Comment: @Tetsujin I have to do that with many icons and want to automate the process. E.g. I may want to redesign the outer image later. Also I figured I should finally get a better understanding of imagemagick ;).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may wish to try something like the following:

```
magick convert circle.png inner.png -gravity Center -geometry 256x256+30+5 -composite -resize 64x64 output.png
```

Where:

- [-gravity Center](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gravity) tells ImageMagick to center any "subimage" (`inner.png`) relative to the background image (`circle.png`).
- [-geometry 256x256+30+5](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry) resizes `inner.png` to `256x256` then offsets its position 30 pixels horizontally to the right (+) and 5 pixels vertically down (+). This offset is considered to be relative to its current position (affected by `‑gravity`, above).
- [-composite](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#composite) take the first image (`circle.png`) and overlays the second image (`inner.png`) according to the current [-compose](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#compose) setting ([which defaults to a value of `Over`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#compose_terms)). The location of the overlaid image (`inner.png`) is controlled by the `-gravity` and `-geometry` settings.

**Results**

*ex. Final Composite Image (`-resize 256x256 output.png`)*

[image: Composite Play Button]

Comment: A perfect answer, thanks! What still surprises me is that swapping `-gravity` and `-geometry` behaves the same.

Comment: Thanks so much! For me it worked when I removed the keyword `magick` in the beginning, so the command in my case was directly starting with `convert`.

Comment: @bluenote10 Your welcome. Some arguments are positional but many aren't.

Comment: @JohannesLemonde Not a problem. But to your comment, using the `magick` keyword depends on your installation of ImageMagick (newer installations i.e. v7+ are more likely to use it/have it available).